# plotmath: how to use a function definition in a label?

Tags: r

I would like to display the definition of `lambda` in the x axis label. Of course I could adjust it by hand, e.g., like this:

```
lambda <- function(t) 1/t
plot(0~0, xlab=expression(lambda(t)==1/t))
```

But is there a way I can let plotmath display the function just from the definition of `lambda` (so not having to manually adjust `xlab`)?

Comment: How about `plot(0~0, xlab=body(lambda))`?

Comment: Hi, looks good. But how to you avoid evaluation of `body` until the expression is overall evaluated? I tried: `plot(0~0, xlab=expression(lambda(t)==body(lambda)))` but it doesn't print the body anymore.

Comment: You can try `sb <- as.character(as.expression(body('lambda')))` and `plot(0~0, xlab=bquote(lambda==.(sb)))`

Comment: Okay, with the last `lambda` replaced by `lambda(t)` this works. Would you mind posting this as a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
lambda <- function(t) 1/t

sb <- as.character(as.expression(body('lambda')))

plot(0~0, xlab=bquote(lambda(t)==.(sb)))
```